# header file for rational class : no type error

Tags: c++, class, types, header

I have built a rational class, here is my .h file:

```
    #ifndef RATIONAL_H
#define RATIONAL_H
#include <iostream>

using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

class Rational
{
    public:
        Rational();
        Rational(int n);
        Rational(int n, int d); 
        Rational(const Rational& other); 

        ~Rational();

        Rational operator+(const Rational& other);
        Rational operator-(const Rational& other);
        Rational operator*(const Rational& other);
        Rational operator/(const Rational& other);

        Rational operator+(int n);
        Rational operator-(int n);
        Rational operator*(int n);
        Rational operator/(int n);

        Rational& operator=(const Rational& other);

        bool operator==(const Rational& other);
        bool operator!=(const Rational& other);
        bool operator>=(const Rational& other);
        bool operator<=(const Rational& other);
        bool operator<(const Rational& other);
        bool operator>(const Rational& other);

        bool operator==(int n);
        bool operator!=(int n);
        bool operator>=(int n);
        bool operator<=(int n);
        bool operator<(int n);
        bool operator>(int n);


        friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Rational &r);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& is, Rational &r);

    private:
        int
            num,
            den;
};

#endif // RATIONAL_H
```

I am getting multiple errors, my main being:

> include\Rational.h|8|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Rations'
>   with no type [-fpermissive]|
>
> include\Rational.h|41|error: 'istream' does not name a type|
>
> include\Rational.h|42|error: 'ostream' does not name a type|

and the rest in my main file (which are all cause because I tried to use >> and <<). I have searched for hours now, found similar problems, tried multiple solutions I don't want to shoot in the dark, I want to know what the problem is and why. For the record here is what I have for Rations in my implementation file:

```
Rational::Rations(int n)
{
    num = n;
    den = 1;
}
```

Let me know if my  complete cpp implementation file or main is needed to solve this.. Also, I am using codeblocks, I have added include into my compiler in build options.

Comment: `error: 'istream' does not name a type` try using `std::istream` instead of `istream`.

Comment: @drescherjm: You're barking up the wrong tree there.  Think `include`

Comment: Include what? iostream? I have it in my main, I tried to move it to .h and that still didn't solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to intend that `Rations(int)` should be a constructor for you class, but the name of the constructor must be the same as the name of the class:

```
Rational::Rational(int n)
```

If it was not a typo then I have no idea why you changed `Rational` to `Rations`.

As for `istream` and `ostream`, your class refers to them, but you haven't declared them-- the compiler has no idea what you're talking about. You must either include the proper headers in your header file (*above* the class definition):

```
#include <istream>
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
```

or, if you're going to be really strict about it, use forward declaration above the class definition:

```
class istream;
class ostream;
```

and then put the `#include` directives in your source code, above the function definitions.

Comment: After making the chages, I am now getting these errors for my implementation file: error: 'istream' in 'class Rational' does not name a type| AND error: 'ostream' in 'class Rational' does not name a type|,

Comment: @minusila: That's strange; could you edit your question to show the new header file? You can omit just about everything inside the class definition except the `friend` lines.

Comment: @minusila: That compiles for me without error (once I write a few function definitions). This will probably turn out to be something small. I suggest you simplify the code as much as you can; remove all of the members but keep one of the `friend` lines, then include that header in a minimal main file (`HelloWorld.cc`). Change `operator<<` to `foo`, and simplify the signature. When you get down to the simplest code that produces the error, the bug may be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors have the same name as the class and have no return type.

Your function `Rations` is spelled differently and either needs a return type of `void` (not returning a value) or it needs to return a value.

Comment: So would changing it to Rational do it? I want it to take an integer n and initialize the object to n / 1..